# Web2PY status of hypermedia for generating REST API for database tables

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

We are creating REST API for tables in my database. We are using Web2PY for the same. Found this old [link](http://web2py.narkive.com/rcgePcSC/database-access-layer-not-to-be-confused-with-database-abstraction-layer) which says we can use hypermedia. However, I see that last year the example was removed from the default.py(controller). Would like to understand what is the status? Is it still experimental as mentioned in the mail?

Any other suggestions to approach the above problem will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [hypermedia module](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/b2e03c9dee935d46cb9512f0595dc2dacddb5166/gluon/contrib/hypermedia.py) is still in gluon.contrib, but I don't think it has received much further development attention. Feel free to use it, though.

Another effort that might be of interest is [APIMaker](https://experts4solutions.com/collection2/default/examples).

Finally, there is the DAL's [parse_as_rest](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#parse_as_rest--experimental-) and [smart_query](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#smart_query--experimental-) functionality (the latter is used to provide the advanced search functionality of [SQLFORM.grid](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-grid-and-SQLFORM-smartgrid)). These are still marked as "experimental" but are fairly stable and will likely continue to be supported.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony this is very helpful.